# how to get html element by name in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know the selector used for name is `$('input[name=xyz]')`
but what if I have a condition ex.

```
 if (input.is("[name=listItem,GrdFromDateTime,GrdToDateTime,GrdRemarks]"))
```

how can I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep the names in an array and check if the current input `name` attribute is in the array.

```
var names = ["listItem", "GrdFromDateTime", "GrdToDateTime", "GrdRemarks"];

if(names.indexOf(input.attr('name')) !== -1) {
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var validValues = "listItem,GrdFromDateTime,GrdToDateTime,GrdRemarks";

if ( validValues.split(",").indexOf( input.attr("name") !== -1 )
```

I thought you were wanted to check if all complete string is matching

Comment: @vijayP from the quested posted by OP I thought he wanted to match the entire set of string.

Comment: @vijayP and now I just realized that my answer is same as Tushar

Comment: No. He is looking for OR condition.

Comment: @vijayP got it now and also brought some variation vis-a-vis Tushar :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input").is("[name=listItem], [name="GrdFromDateTime"]...)
```